# AJAX function is not getting the correct response from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have written a script i JQuery and PHP,
After the success return from PHP, AJAX function should catch a success response but I am not getting that.
Below is the code:

```
$.ajax({

                    url     :"script_admin-add-category.php",
                    method  :"POST",
                    data    :{lExpensesId:lcl_ExpensesId},

                    success:function(data){
                        //if(data=="ok"){
                            if(data=="YES"){
                                alert("EMAIL");
                            }else{
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        //}
                        //if(data=="ok"){
                            //alert("Expenses Id already exists!");
                        //}else{
                            //alert(data);
                        //}
                    }

        });
```

and here is the php code

```
//Check connection
    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
//echo "helloooo";
            if(isset($_POST["lExpensesId"])){
                $lExpensesId    = $_POST["lExpensesId"];
                    $Lquery = "SELECT ExpensesId FROM tblexpensestype WHERE ExpensesId = '$lExpensesId'";
                    if($query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $Lquery)){

                            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_result )){
                                echo 'YES';
                            }else{
                                //echo "Proceed";
                            }
                    }else{
                        echo "Not Okay";
                    }
            }else{

            }
    }
```

I can see the echo value on browser and alert value also. But if condition is not working for success function???

Comment: What response code are you getting in your network console?  That should always be your first stop debugging ajax to verify that the request happened and what response it got.

Comment: I am getting "YES" only. Actually, it should display YES and EMAIL

Comment: I am betting it is more that just yes.

Comment: `console.log( escape(data) )`

Comment: Yaar, echo will return the value to AJAX? And why not?

Comment: What is "response code"????

Comment: Crack open your developer tools man, F12.  Or right click on your page and inspect element to open them.  Then find the tab/place that says "Network".  As I stated in my first comment, this is the first place you should go to see what is going on with your ajax requests.  Once you have that open, make your ajax request happen again and see what is returned.  EDIT: Also for future reading http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide33

Comment: I can see status is 200

Comment: change this line `alert("EMAIL");` to this `alert("EMAIL: " + data);` and you will see YES and EMAIL. Actually also using this line `alert("YES EMAIL")` you will see YES and EMAIL

Comment: And what is being returned in the response?  Click the request and a side panel will appear on the right that should have a response tab on it.

Comment: Not able to see any return???

Comment: So the response tab is blank?  Edit: Side note I'm surprised no one has brought up the possible sql injection attack the php logic currently has.

Comment: @Taplar here an sql injection will fix things instead of damage it

Comment: Boss, I am using the ajax in the same way on other pages and  I am getting proper return....

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try set correct data type for returned data.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'script_admin-add-category.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {lExpensesId: lcl_ExpensesId},
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function (data) {
    if (data === 'YES') {
      alert('EMAIL')
    } else {
      alert(data)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: hi, it does not matter

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

@J Salaria  as i understood your question you are having problem with `jquery AJAX` and `PHP` code as you are not getting you desired result. There are different ways to send the data through jquery ajax which i will be explain in detail.

`$_POST["lExpensesId"]` are you getting this ID from a `HTML <form>` ?.Because here i'll be showing you 3 different practiced ways to send data through ajax..

> NOTE: YOUR CODE IS VULNERABLE TO SQL INJECION. I'LL BE ALSO SHOWING YOU THE METHODS TO OVERCOME.IF YOU WANT TO LEARN MORE ABOUT SQL INJECTION CLICK ON THIS LINK [SQL INJECTION LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

HTML FORM CODE :

```
<form action="" id="send_lExpensesId_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="lExpensesId" id="lExpensesId" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

FIRST WAY FOR SENDING DATA THIS IS THOUGH `HTML <FORM>`

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send_lExpensesId_form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var form_serialize = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'script_admin-add-category.php',
                data:form_serialize,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data == "YES"){
                        alert("EMAIL");
                    }else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

SECOND WAY FOR SENDING DATA THIS IS THOUGH `HTML <FORM>`

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send_lExpensesId_form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var form_serialize = new FormData($(this)[0]);


            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'script_admin-add-category.php',
                data:form_serialize,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data == "YES"){
                        alert("EMAIL");
                    }else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

THIRD WAY FOR SENDING DATA THIS IS USED `WHEN A LINK CLICKED OR TO DELETED THROUGH ID OR CLASS`

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send_lExpensesId_form").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var lcl_ExpensesId = $("#lExpensesId").val();

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'script_admin-add-category.php',
                data:{lExpensesId:lcl_ExpensesId},
                success:function(data){
                    if(data == "YES"){
                        alert("EMAIL");
                    }else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

HERE IT THE PHP CODE WITH `mysqli_real_escape_string();` AGAINST SQL INJECTION

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "admin";
    $dbname = "demo";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST["lExpensesId"])){
        $lExpensesId = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["lExpensesId"]);

        $Lquery = "SELECT ExpensesId FROM tblexpensestype WHERE ExpensesId = '$lExpensesId'";
        if($query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $Lquery)){

            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_result )){
                echo 'YES';
            }else{
                echo "Proceed";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }
?>
```

HERE IT THE OTHER PHP CODE WITH `MYSQLI->PREPARED` WHICH IS BETTER AGAINST SQL INJECTION

```
<?php
    // WITH MYSQLI PREPARED STATEMENT AGAINST SQL INJECTION
    $sql = $conn->stmt_init();
        $Lquery = "SELECT ExpensesId FROM tblexpensestype WHERE ExpensesId =?";
        if($sql->prepare($Lquery)){
            $sql->bind_param('i',$lExpensesId);
            $sql->execute();
            $sql->store_result();

            if($sql->num_rows > 0){
                echo 'YES';
            }else{
                echo "Proceed";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
        }
?>
```

## I HOPE YOU GOT ANSWERE FOR YOU QUESTION IF YOU HAVE OTHER DOUBTS FEEL FREE AND COMMENT BELOW

Answer (score 0):

All methods are known and many thanks for assistance. My question is that Why I am not able to get proper return from PHP. Below is my code:

```
var lcl_ExpensesId = $("#IExpensesId").val();
            //alert(lcl_ExpensesId);
        $.ajax({

                    url     :"script_admin-add-category.php",
                    method  :"POST",
                    data    :{lExpensesId:lcl_ExpensesId},
                    success:function(data){
                        if(data=="ok"){
                            alert("Inserted");
                        }else{
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    }
        });
ob_start();
```

/*------------------FUNCTION TO READ ACCOUNTS DROPDOWN EXPENSES LIST -----------------------*/

```
require_once 'db_config.php';
$newlist    = fxn_CONFIGURATION();
$HOST       = $newlist[0];
$DBNAME     = $newlist[1];
$UNAME      = $newlist[2];
$PSWD       = $newlist[3];
$conn   =   mysqli_connect($HOST, $UNAME, $PSWD, $DBNAME);


    //Check connection
    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection Failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
    }else{
            if(isset($_POST["lExpensesId"])){

                $lExpensesId    = $_POST["lExpensesId"];

                    $Lquery = "SELECT ExpensesId FROM tblexpensestype WHERE ExpensesId = '$lExpensesId'";
                    $query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $Lquery);

                            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_result) > 0){
                                echo "ok";
                            }else{
                                echo "Proceed";
                            }

            }
    }       
mysqli_close($conn);


ob_flush();
```

As, i am using this AJAX in my one of input keyup method so whatever I will type, each and everytime, it will execute PHP script. I am having a item as FOOD in databse. When i type "F", I got Proceed, "O" - Proceed, "O" - Proceed, "D" - ok....
When I type D, i should get "Inserted" instead of Ok....
This is my doubt that why i m getting this????

Comment: @J Salaria if you are using words to search then you should be using `SQL LIKE OR WILDCARD QUERY` using `ExpensesId = '$lExpensesId'` will not give you right answere..  `$Lquery = "SELECT ExpensesId FROM tblexpensestype WHERE ExpensesId LIKE '%$lExpensesId%'";`

Comment: I am wondering that you guys are not able to understand the question. I am posting something and you guys are keeping posting something else.....
Many thanks for telling me about wildcards.
Please, have a look on the question and all post posted by me....

Comment: Here, I have got something new in sources breakpoint on if(data=="ok"),
I can see the output of data is "Proceed-----" - means enter key simple

Comment: HI, As I am getting as 
ocal
Return value
:
undefined
response
:
"Proceed
↵
↵
↵
↵
↵"
this
:
Object

Instead of "Proceed"... Any one tell me the reason for this

Answer (score 0):

The above problem is resolved by using exit() statement in PHP as I am getting five ↵↵↵↵↵ after my values and it means I am having 5 lines of html without closing ?>. So the best way to resolve the issue is to use exit() in PHP as per need